# How to call Okta Add Person API from our application?

Tags: okta, okta-api

In Okta we have an in-built feature under users>>People>>Add Person

Can someone help me understand how to call okta Add Person api from our application?

Answer (score 1):

you can download the okta users api postman doc

```
https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/users/
```

the creation of person is under the `Create User` area
[image]

note: you need to generate an api key to call these endpoints. 
login to okta dashboard as administrator and generate an api key.

after adding the person 
you can call the lifecycle operation endpoints to active/deactivate/delete a user

[image]